# mySQL JOIN on one to many

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have multiple tables that are linked together on the search page. They are currently queried like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tripreportentries 
    JOIN tripreport ON tripreportentries.reportid = tripreport.tripreportid 
    JOIN user_details on tripreportentries.userid = user_details.userid
WHERE TripEntryHeading LIKE '%%' AND tripreportentries.ispublic = 1
ORDER BY tripreportentryid
```

I have since created a new table called tripphotos with the table columns named:

- tripphotoid
- reportid
- entryid
- photoname

The issue is each entry can have more than one corresponding photo in the photo table.

I am looking to find a way to JOIN the new table to the statement above but not return several rows for each entry id.

Any ideas on how to join this table?

EDIT - I also want to just tie one image to the returned row and not all of them just so I can show the image as a thumbnail on the browse page

Comment: Hmm ... just a guess; use `group_concat()` and then join probably.

Comment: "ideas on how to join this table?" Use a subquery (inline view) limit 1 or use aggregates.  The question you have to ask yourself is WHICH image you want returned.  You could use aggregation and return min/Max photo; assuming that's ok.  But if you really care which photo, requirements need to be clairified.  You could use a sub query limit results by 1 and sort by EntryId desc or ascending as well if you want the most recent/oldest for each record

Comment: @xQbert thanks for your response. I have no real interest at this time in which image is returned, that will be a phase 2 change and I will change the whole structure and how this page works to do that. Just looking for a quick solution at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally would list every column and group by the non aggregates, but mySQL will allow this I believe; given the mySQL group by extensions; and we expect the tripReport and user_Details columns to be the same for each joined photoname.

```
SELECT tripReport.*, user_details.*, max(photoname) as maxPhotoPerReport 
    FROM tripreportentries 
    JOIN tripreport ON tripreportentries.reportid = tripreport.tripreportid 
    JOIN user_details ON tripreportentries.userid = user_details.userid
    JOIN tripphotos ON tripreportentries.reportid = tripPhotos.ReportID
WHERE TripEntryHeading LIKE '%%' AND tripreportentries.ispublic = 1
GROUP BY ReportId
ORDER BY tripreportentryid
```

or we could do this using an inline view to get the max photo for each report and then join that set to your base query.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM tripreportentries 
    JOIN tripreport ON tripreportentries.reportid = tripreport.tripreportid 
    JOIN user_details on tripreportentries.userid = user_details.userid
    JOIN (SELECT max(photoName) as MaxPhotoPerReport, ReportID 
          FROM TripPhotos 
          GROUP BY  ReportID) B 
        ON B.ReportID = tripReport.ReportId
WHERE TripEntryHeading LIKE '%%' AND tripreportentries.ispublic = 1
ORDER BY tripreportentryid
```

Comment: this has helped me resolve the issue but isn't exactly right as it was returning the same photo for every row even if the photo did not match to that entryi, but I got it fixed from this.

Comment: I assumed the join criteria based on names.  Was it a problem with the Join relationships?